# include jQuery plugin in html page without downloading the plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I want to include a jQuery plugin in an html page, but i want this plugin to be included whenever someone from my office creates this html page without forcing them to download the plugin.
To be more specific, i have php script that creates html table. that is the beginning (relevant part) of the script:

```
$pre .= '<html>';
$pre .= '<head>';
$pre .= '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>';
$pre .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/bar/Downloads/tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> ';
$pre .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
$pre .= '</head>';
$pre .= '<body>';
```

now, what will consider to be an elegant way to include the [tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) plugin, **not** from a local computer. I thought about using cdn maybe but than i never tried to deal with it so i want to know if there is a better solution, or if cdn its my answer?? and if so...is there a free way to do it? thx

Comment: So basically you are looking for a location to store a .js file?

Comment: This is what CDNs do. As an alternative, you could have scrips stored in your own server and provide that link instead.

Comment: "whenever someone from my office creates this html" Can you elaborate on this? How does the application work?
"without forcing them to download the plugin" How else will the JS execute? The browser needs to download the script (fetch it from the cdn or your own server)

Comment: creats this html = executes the php script (i included a part of it), for the sake of this question i believe its enough to say that executing the php script generates the html file. "How else the JS execute?"? well thats kind of the all idea behind my question, to try and learn of a new solution rather than using cdn

Comment: where is the php script? on your web server? how does the user execute the php script?

Answer (score 0):

I thing the problem what you are trying to solve is to include la tablesorter script only once so that client does not have to download it, or have it on his computer.
 This is my proposition :

The reference to the script is not absolute no

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/bar/Download/tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> ';
```

but

```
'<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter-master/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> ';
```

supposing that  tablesorter-master is a directory and your php file is in the same folder with it.
Hence only your php server with contains the library.